# crodova-google-maps plugin doesn't show map (Ionic 2 + Angular 2)

Tags: google-maps, typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic2

Installed cordova-google-maps plugin with Google Api key.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="myKeyHere" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="myKeyHere"
```

Created container for map in one of mine child elements template:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"></div>
```

Made service, that will create map:

```
import { Injectable, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleMap, GoogleMapsLatLng } from 'ionic-native';

@Injectable()
export class MapService {
    public customMap: GoogleMap;

    constructor() {
    }

    public loadMap(container: string) {
        let location = new GoogleMapsLatLng('65.9667', '-18.5333');

        this.customMap = new GoogleMap(container);

        GoogleMap.isAvailable().then(data => {
            this.customMap.animateCamera({target: location, zoom: 10});
        });
    }
 }
```

And calling map creation from child component, when component is ready (pressing the button):

```
this.mapService.loadMap('map_canvas');
```

"loadMap" function doesn't get any errors. After it's complete, all parent elements include child element (where was created container for map with id "map_canvas") getting css class "_gmaps_cdv_" which makes background transparent.

But map doesn't show, plus component, where map was created wont show too.
Am i doing something wrong? Or can somebody guide me, how to show google-map on wanted component. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-maps-dont-work/55637 if you've not already looked at it

Answer (score 0):

Dunno, didn't find any solution (goole-maps just appeared in my root component with gray background, also made background of all child element transparent).

Choosed Static Map Api (also from google). It returns picture of map based on location coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue in Ionic 2. I have invested my 3 days into this. Below things solved my problem.

- Your Google API Key &  - You can check Google Console to verify your API hits coming or not.

**Home.html**

```
<ion-header class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank Map
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div #map id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

**Home.scss**

```
page-home ion-content {
  background: rgb(229, 227, 223);
}

page-home #map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in
}

.home-page{
  #map{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

page-home #map.show-map {
  opacity: 1;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Geolocation, GoogleMapsEvent, GoogleMapsLatLng, GoogleMap, CameraPosition, GoogleMapsMarkerOptions,  GoogleMapsMarker} from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  map:any;
  MarkerData = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private platform: Platform) {     
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        //alert('this.platform.ready');
        this.obtenerPosicion();
    })
  }

  obtenerPosicion():any{
    //alert('obtenerPosicion');
    let options = {timeout:10000, enableHighAccuracy:true, maximumAge:2000};

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((position) => {

        //alert('Geolocation getCurrentPosition');
          console.log(position.coords);
          let coordenada = [{
            'longitude' : position.coords.longitude,
            'latitude' : position.coords.latitude
          }];
          console.log(coordenada);
          this.loadMap(coordenada);

      }, (err) => {

        ////alert(err);
        console.log(err);

        //alert('Error in obtenerPosicion');

        let coordenadaDefault = [{
          'longitude' : 78.9629,
          'latitude' : 20.5937
          // 'longitude' : 150.644,
          // 'latitude' : -34.397
        }];
        this.loadMap(coordenadaDefault);
        //alert("The Geolocation faild. Please Search location manually.");

      });
  }

  loadMap(coordenada:any[]){
      //alert('loadMap');
      let mapEle = document.getElementById('map');
      mapEle.classList.add('show-map');


      console.log(coordenada);
      let longitud = coordenada[0]['longitude'];
      let latitude = coordenada[0]['latitude'];
      // let location: crea un objeto con las coordenadas latitude y longitud y es pasada a las // opciones de google maps.

      //alert('Set location');
      let location = new GoogleMapsLatLng(latitude,longitud);
      //alert(location);

      this.map = new GoogleMap('map', {
          'backgroundColor': 'white',
          'controls': {
          'compass': true,
          'myLocationButton': true,
          'indoorPicker': true,
          'zoom': true,
        },
        'gestures': {
          'scroll': true,
          'tilt': true,
          'rotate': true,
          'zoom': true
        }
        // ,'camera': {
        //   'latLng': location,
        //   'tilt': 30,
        //   'zoom': 15,
        //   'bearing': 50
        // }
      });


      this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Map is ready!');
        //alert('Map is ready!');


          this.map.addMarker({
              'position': location,
              'icon': 'green',
              'title': "Pickup Location",
              'draggable': true
            }, function(marker) {

              marker.showInfoWindow();

                //Drag event of marker
                  marker.addEventListener(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_DRAG_END, function(marker) {
                    marker.getPosition(function(latLng) {
                      marker.setTitle(latLng.toUrlValue());
                      marker.showInfoWindow();
                    });
                  });

                //alert('Marker added.');          
            });

            this.map.animateCamera({
                'target': location,
                'tilt': 0,
                'zoom': 15,
                'bearing': 0,
                'duration': 3000 // = 3 sec.
              }, function() {
                console.log("The animation is done");
                //alert('The animation is done.');                            
              });



      });


      //alert('mapEle classList Add show-map');
  }

}
```

In LoadMap method I have added below code. This will set the class & class will apply the opacity. After adding this line my map get started showing. If I commented this I will not get any hit on my Google console API dashboard.

```
let mapEle = document.getElementById('map');
mapEle.classList.add('show-map');
```

*** Note** :- Ionic View will not show map control & Browser also not show you the native map control. Only option to test this is to deploy your app on your device by **ionic run android**

Please let me know still you face any issue.

Comment: Can we integrate google map on any page other than homepage?